# Django accessing model attributes from Manager

Tags: django, django-managers

I've got following model:

```
class Hospitalization(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    date_in = models.DateField()
    date_out = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I'd like to list the current Hospitalizations. So I added a @property 'is_current':

```
@property
def is_current(self):
    today = date.today()
    if self.date_in and self.date_out:
        if self.date_in <= today and self.date_out >= today:
            return True
    if self.date_in and not self.date_out:
        if self.date_in <= today:
            return True
```

When trying to call the property from a filter in my views.py however, I get following error though: *Cannot resolve keyword 'is_current' into field. Choices are: date_in, date_out, id, patient, room*

Then I thought I could do this with a Manager. So I added a Manager:

```
class Hospitalization(models.Model):
    def get_query_set(self):
        today = date.today()
        if self.date_in and self.date_out:
            return qs.filter(date_in__lte=today, date_out__gte=today)
        if self.date_in and not self.date_out:
            return qs.filter(date_in__lte=today)
```

But that doesn't work either: *AttributeError: 'HospitalizationManager' object has no attribute 'date_in'*

What would be the Django recommended way to fix this?

Comment: is `if self.date_in` really necessary if date_in cannot be null by definition?

Comment: It isn't. :-) Using the Q objects I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thanks @asermax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your `Manager`:

- You're subclassing `Model`, not `Manager`.
- You're using your model attributes as if they belonged to the `Manager`, **which they don't**.
- Your custom `get_queryset` isn't calling the superclass method, so it's using an undefined `qs` attribute.

The correct way to define your manager would be:

```
class CurrentHospitalizationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(CurrentHospitalizationManager, self).get_query_set()
        today = date.today()    
        return qs.filter(
            # we can use Q objects here to check if the date_out exists or not
            # and compare against the current date if necesary
            models.Q(date_out__isnull=True) | models.Q(date_out__gte=today),
            date_in__lte=today                
        )
```

Then you should assign the manager to a class attribute on your model, like this

```
class Hospitalization(models.Model):
    current_objects = CurrentHospitalizationManager()
    ...
```

And use it on your code like this:

```
Hospitalization.current_objects.get(...) # or filter, or whatever
```

**I don't recommend** you assign this custom manager to your default manager attr (`objects`), since you wouldn't be able to access the `Hospitalization`'s instances that aren't "current".

[Custom Manager's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I had never worked with Q before. 
But something doesn't seem to be working though: as soon as I combine the 'date_in__lte=today' inside the qs.filter() (as shown in the example), then I get a 'SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg' at validation of the Model.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the comma between the two arguments in filter(). I fixed it by chaining two filters: `return qs.filter(date_in__lte=today).filter(models.Q(date_out__isnull=True) | models.Q(date_out__gte=today))`. Thanks!

Comment: And two more addition if somebody else would have a similar issue: `get_queryset()` should be `get_query_set()`, and `super(HospitalizationManager, self)` should be `super(CurrentHospitalizationManager, self)`.

Comment: The first issue can be fixed either chaining filters as you did or changing the position of the args (since that's the error is giving after all). Fixed the issues on the answer, sorry for that :]